# Reset HTML form fields (avoid undo capability)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've an issue in SPA (single page application based on AngularJS).

Scenario:

1. The user login to the system using navbar that contains username and password, behind the scene I'm resetting the form that contains the login and pass..
2. The user presses a link to his/her profile.
3. Pressing the navbar logoff button I'm sending the user to the home page.
4. If I stand in the username input control and press Control + Z to undo I get the username and another Control + Z retrieves the password as well.

How I can reset the undo (history) functionality of these two fields.

BTW: If I'm refreshing the page it is gone.

Thank you,
Chen

Answer (score 3):

This looks to be a problem (or feature?) in IE and Firefox, but doesn't seem to happen in Chrome.

A quick-and-dirty way to clear the undo history from the input boxes is to remove them from the DOM and add them back. In Angular we can use `ngIf`...

```
<input ng-model="user.username" type="text"     ng-if="enabled" placeholder="Username" />
<input ng-model="user.password" type="password" ng-if="enabled" placeholder="Password" />
```

When clearing the textboxes, toggle the `enabled` property...

```
$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.enabled = false;
    $timeout(function () { $scope.enabled = true });
};
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bf0egfuu/)